# How to check if there is a related row and also a missing row

Tags: sql, oracle, compare

I apologize for the poor wording of my question title. I am fairly new to SQL and I am not really sure what I would call this type of comparison query.

I have a couple of tables and I need to query them to see if someone with a user account also does not have a mailing address on file. Addresses are stored in the same table regardless of whether they are mailing or physical. The difference is just indicated by a type column that will be either 'M' or 'P'. So users should have 2 rows associated with them, one for their mailing address and one for their physical address.

```
//I want to do something like this
SELECT * FROM 
    USER
    , ADDR
WHERE USER.ADDR_ID =  ADDR.ID
AND ADDR.TYPE      = 'P'; 

SELECT * FROM 
    USER
    , ADDR
WHERE USER.ADDR_ID =  ADDR.ID
AND ADDR.TYPE      = 'M';
```

And then find users with one address with type = 'P' but no address with type = 'M'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aggregation or `not exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where exists (select 1 from addr a where u.addr_id = a.id and a.type = 'P') and
      not exists (select 1 from addr a where u.addr_id = a.id and a.type = 'M')
```

Comment: Also left outer join is an option.